# Enable Sharepoint Access Request Setting Without Outgoing mail config

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have read in many sites that access request setting feature in SharePoint 2013 cannot be enabled if outgoing mail server is not configured in SP servers. But I want to know is there a way to enable 'Access Request Setting' in Site Permissions without configuring outgoing mail?Any workaround?like PowerShell Scripts. Or can we atleast set the 'Request Access Mail' to any email id without configuring outgoing mail?

Comment: I believe it is not possible to use the OOB access request feature without enabling outgoing email. If not through the email, how do you plan to manage the access requests ? How do you want to notify the owner/admin that an access request has come in ?

Comment: @VipulKelkar I understand that. But its a client requirment. Can we atleast set the RequestAccessMail to any particular email id without outgoing mail configuration? I have tried to acheive it using PS script it didn't allow. Is there any way for that?

Comment: It is not possible to set it without outgoing email configuration in place. Check [this](https://spcafcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CSC510215_SPWebRequestAccessEmailPropertyUsage)